# DevExpress LookupEdit - setting the selected DataRow by code

Tags: c#, controls, devexpress

**I am aware that there other questions like this, but their solutions do not work for me.**

I have the following code:

> ```
>      lueSizes.Properties.DataSource = new BindingSource(PS.PaperSizes, null);
>      lueSizes.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("PaperName", "Größe"));
>      lueSizes.Properties.DisplayMember = "PaperName";
>      lueSizes.Properties.ValueMember = "PaperName";
>
>      //PS is a regular System PrinterSettings object
>      foreach (PaperSize size in PS.PaperSizes)
>
>          //I confirmed with debugging that this actually happens correctly
>          if (size.RawKind == binSettings.SizeRawKind)
>           {
>               lueSizes.EditValue = size;
>               break;
>           }
> ```

Populating the LookupEdit with the DataSource works fine, the user can select the desired PaperSize from the dropdown, and

> lueSizes.GetSelectedDataRow() as PaperSize

then returns a PaperSize object as expected.

The problem I have is setting the EditValue, it simply does nothing. I have verified that at runtime, the DataSource contains all the PaperSize objects in PS.PaperSizes, including the one that is found in the foreach loop. But setting EditValue = size does not cause the selected data row to update accordingly.

Other variations I have tried are:

> lueSizes.EditValue = size.PaperName;
>
> lueSizes.EditValue = lueSizes.Properties.GetKeyValueByDisplayText(size.PaperName);
>
> lueSizes.EditValue = lueSizes.Properties.GetKeyValueByDisplayValue(size.PaperName);
>
> lueSizes.EditValue = lueSizes.Properties.GetKeyValueByDisplayValue(size);
>
> lueSizes.EditValue = 0;

None of these do anything, the selected datarow remains NULL and displays nothing to the user.

**What else can I try to set the selected DataRow by code?**

Edit:

```
    private void lueSizes_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object o = lueSizes.EditValue;
        object p = lueSizes.GetSelectedDataRow();
        PaperSize size = o as PaperSize;
        UpdateSize(size);
    }
```

Object o is the item I have set earlier, the PaperSize size that Ive found in the loop, but object p is null.

Comment: Have you tried RefreshDataSource

Comment: @username no, because the datasource does not change after its declaration, and because LookupEdit does not have that method in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have at least found a workaround:

---

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(PS.PaperSizes, null);
lueSizes.Properties.DataSource = bindingSource;
lueSizes.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("PaperName", "Größe"));
lueSizes.Properties.DisplayMember = "PaperName";

foreach (PaperSize size in bindingSource)
    if (size.RawKind == BinSettings.SizeRawKind)
    {
        lueSizes.EditValue = size;
        break;
    }
```

---

```
private void lueSizes_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PaperSize size = lueSizes.EditValue as PaperSize;
    Update(size);
}
```

---

So first, I let the loop search in the BindingSource, which I have to define explicitely now, instead of the Printersettings object.

Next, I may not set the DisplayValue property.

Finally, I avoid looking up the DataRow and go for the edit value directly. Don't know what limitations

I don't know what else that breaks, if anything, but for now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I just got the same problem. The accepted answer is not the best practice since our goal is to get the selected object rather than the key value. The workaround is to call lookupEdit.Properties.ForceInitialize() right after EditValueChangedEvent got fired and GetSelectedDataRow() should work afterward. This solve the problem if the lookupEdit is not changed via mouse.

Comment: I added lookupEditSelector.Properties.ForceInitializ() in constructor of my Form (containing this control) which made it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to insure that the assigned value is exists in the lookupEdit's datasource,
then try set the `.Text` property directly

To pull the underlying assigned object

```
PaperSize  selectedPS = (PaperSize)lueSizes.Properties.GetDataSourceRowByDisplayValue(lueSizes.Text)
```

Comment: adding lueSizes.Text = size.PaperName; or replacing the "editvalue=" line with it does nothing. GetSelectedDataRow() keeps returning NULL.

Comment: No, it does nothing, as I wrote. The line displayed to the user remains "[EditValue is null]"

Comment: if the `EditValue is null` then the assigned value does not exist in the original datasource!, plus the method `GetSelectedDataRow` not exists in the `DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit` methods! What version of DevExpress you uses? anyway check my post for more updates

Comment: I am using 10.2.8, the GetSelectedDataRow() is this: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdit_GetSelectedDataRowtopic I have checked the datasource at runtime, it does contain all the PaperSize objects in PS.PaperSizes, including the one that is found in the foreach loop. I just don't know why it is not accepted as the EditValue

Comment: I already stated that pulling the currently selected PaperSize is NO PROBLEM and it is NOT my question how to do that. GetSelectedDataRow() as PaperSize works perfectly fine if the user has selected an item from the list. My question is, how do I select an item by code?

Comment: My experience is in v9.1 of the product, seems they added some new methods to the class, anyway; I really don't know what's the problem, but I can encourage you to open a ticket to the DevExpress's developers team on their site.. Good Luck!